# Can't connect to Google Cloud SQL from Cloud Run - using R Shiny

Tags: r, postgresql, shiny, google-cloud-sql, shiny-server

I have created an R Shiny app that connects to a Cloud SQL instance. It runs fine on my local server, but when I upload to either shinyapps.io or to Cloud Run via Dockerfile, it is unable to connect.

Here is the code I am using to connect using RPostgres package:

```
conn <- dbConnect(
    drv=RPostgres::Postgres(),
    dbname='postgres',
    sslrootcert=path to 'server-ca.pem',
    sslcert=path to 'client-cert.pem',
    sslkey=path to 'client-key.pem',
    host='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    port=5432,
    user='username',
    password='password_string',
    sslmode='verify-ca')
```

I've checked the logs in Cloud Run, the error message I am seeing is the following:

> Warning: Error in : unable to find an inherited method for function 'dbGetQuery' for signature '"character", "character"'

The dbGetQuery() function is called after the dbConnect function, and since it runs fine on my local server, I am fairly confident that what I am seeing is a connection issue, rather than a package namespace issue. But could be wrong.

I have opened up to all IPs by adding 0.0.0.0/0 as an allowed network. The weird thing is that OCCASIONALLY I CAN CONNECT from shinyapps.io, but most of the time it fails. I have not yet got it to work once from Cloud Run. This is leading me to think that it could be a problem with a dynamic IP address or something similar?

Do I need to go through the Cloud Auth proxy to connect directly between Cloud Run and Cloud SQL? Or can I just connect via the dbConnect method above? I figured that 0.0.0.0/0 would also include Cloud Run IPs but I probably don't understand how it works well enough. Any explanations would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks very much!

Comment: Is the connection succeeding? You have masked the connection host, but I am guessing you are trying to use IP. The SSL certificate contains the instance name and not the IP address. This means you cannot enable SSL verification for IP based connections. If you are using Unix sockets with Cloud Run, then you do not need the SSL settings at all as the SQL proxy encrypts for you. Follow the Cloud Run documentation and use the SQL instance name (Unix sockets) which uses the proxy to connect and remove the SSL part.

Comment: What I don't understand is how do I obtain the connection once I've used the proxy? I.e. how do I pass it to the 'conn' object in my code (see question)? From what you're saying, I think I just need to pass the SQL instance name to the host parameter?

Comment: The proxy runs hidden to your Cloud Run container. Connect using a Unix socket `/cloudsql/CLOUD_SQL_CONNECTION_NAME`. The connection name is listed in the console or via the CLI `gcloud instances list` and the `gcloud instances describe`. I do not code in R or know how to configure RPostgres to use a Unix socket instead of an IP:PORT. Review this link for connecting to Cloud SQL from Cloud Run: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-run

Comment: Unfortunately that method doesn't seem to work for me, it appears that RPostgres doesn't accept connections from Unix sockets in the way you describe. Does this mean I need to switch to a private IP? And what does that even mean??

Comment: A private IP has even more restrictions. Several options: 1) switch libraries to one that supports Unix sockets. 2) Use a public IP, whitelist your IP address and enable SSL connections. If you chose a private IP then your client must be in your VPC, or you must use the SQL Proxy.

Answer (score 2):

> I have opened up to all IPs by adding 0.0.0.0/0 as an allowed network.

From a security standpoint, this is a terrible, horrible, no good idea. It essentially means the entire world can attempt to connect to your database.

As @john-hanley stated in the comment, the [Connecting Cloud Run to Cloud SQL documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-run) details how to connect. There are two options:

1. via Public IP (the internet) using the Unix domain socket on `/cloudsql/CLOUD_SQL_CONNECTION_NAME`
2. via Private IP, which connects through a VPC using the Serverless VPC Access

If a Unix domain socket is not supported by your library, you'll have to use a different library or choose Option 2 and connect over TCP. Note that Serverless VPC Access connector has additional costs associated with using it.

Comment: I'm definitely aware of the warnings about this. However, my understanding was that as long as the queries are SSL encrypted and you have a strong password, that's still at least 2 layers of security that any hacker has to bypass before they can hack your system. Is this correct? I assume that if Cloud SQL makes it available as an option, then there is at least some merit to the idea.